# Error when building omnet++ with inet project

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have error messages when try to build project using omnet++ with inet

```
15:56:39 **** Incremental Build of configuration release for project 
FirstProject ****
make MODE=release all 
cd src && /usr/bin/make
make[1]: Entering directory '/c/omnetpp-5.6.2/samples/FirstProject/src'
Creating executable: ../out/clang-release/src/FirstProject.exe
C:\omnetpp-5.6.2\tools\win64\mingw64\bin\ld: cannot find -lINET
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[1]: *** [Makefile:101: ../out/clang-release/src/FirstProject.exe] 
Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/omnetpp-5.6.2/samples/FirstProject/src'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
"make MODE=release all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be 
incomplete.

15:56:40 Build Failed. 3 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.125ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that Inet is correctly referenced in your FirstProject?
Right Click on First Project - > Properties - > Project References - > Mark Inet.
Another reason can be an error compiling Inet.

Comment: Thank you for answer , I marked it ,but stills the same errors @alex31

Comment: make[1]: *** [Makefile:1746: ../out/clang-release/src/libINET.dll] Error 1

Comment: Are you able to find the inet compiling error. Does the console help??

Comment: You won't be able to compile your project till inet compiles error free

Comment: the line above in my comment show the INET compiling error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778355/problem-in-building-inet-in-omnet-5-6-2

Comment: Which version of INET are you trying to compile?? I read the text in link. Seems there is an empty function in the described module (Ieee80211). Usually it indicates a compatibility problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing clang,clang++